# Apply command to files which names match a regular expression

Tags: command-line, bash, unix

For example, I want to apply `chmod 777` to every file in some directory which name matches some regular expression. Sure I can do stuff like `chmod 777 f*`, but when it comes to something more complicated, I don't know how to do it. For example, I can't run `chmod 777 *a{3,5}`.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `find`'s `-regex` to find files matching a regular expression and use `xargs` to `chmod` the matched files.

```
$ ls -l
total 320
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 2011-10-01 09:38 baaaaaaat
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 2011-10-01 09:38 baaat
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 2011-10-01 09:38 baat
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 2011-10-01 09:38 bat
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 2011-10-01 09:38 boo
$ find ./  -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*a{3,5}.*' -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0777
$ ls -l
total 320
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 0 2011-10-01 09:38 baaaaaaat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 0 2011-10-01 09:38 baaat
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 2011-10-01 09:38 baat
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 2011-10-01 09:38 bat
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 2011-10-01 09:38 boo
$
```